# What is the plural of "кочерга"?

Tags: множественное-число

I am reading a Russian book and at one point I was a little confused, as to how one would say plural of "кочерга".

Comment: information about this and many other words regarding declension may be found in https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's кочерги, though yes it used relatively rare. Here's how it's inclined:

- *Им.* кочерги́
- *Р.*  кочерёг
- *Д.*  кочерга́м
- *В.*  кочерги́
- *Тв.* кочерга́ми
- *Пр.* кочерга́х

PS. Actually it's not non-standard, and it would be nice if you'd tried at least to google beforehand. Information of this kind [easily](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0) can be found. (My guess is that's the reason you've been downvoted.)

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I should have, but now there is no going back.:(

Comment: It would be useful to show the position of stress for the nominative case: maybe it's the main difficulty with this word in plural.

Comment: @Alex_ander can not agree more, added stresses for all cases, thank you for the hint!